# Como puedo borrar todas las carpetas llamadas "nombrex" dentro de un Disco?

Tags: batch

Buen día. Quiero borrar todas las CARPETAS del mismo NOMBRE y SUB-CARPETAS del MISMO NOMBRE (Disculpen redundancia) de un disco duro de 2 petabytes pero obviamente son demasiados  CARPETAS que revisar.

El nombre de dicha carpeta es "nombrex". Está en mas de 2 millones de carpetas tambien en subcarpetas y quiero Borrar todas ellas por codigo Batch.

Me imagino es algo como esto:

```
del /s/e "C:\" nombrex
```

Por favor si algien me ayuda este tema.

Comment: Qué pasa cuando pruebas tu código?

Comment: Pruebalo @Alfabravo hehe :), es broma de hecho me parece que /e tal vez no sea una opción.

Comment: es borrar una carpeta con `"nombrex"` recursivamente dentro de otras carpetas?

Comment: Hay edite lo que pido es que de verdad son muchas carpetas me quedo corto con 2 PetaBytes los archivos los tengo en la Nube y sincroniza con mi pc de casa entonces son Infinita cantidad de CARPETAS.

Comment: ahí te puse una forma de hacerlo, el servicio de sincronización no trae opción de hacerlo desde la nube?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay una forma de hacerlo encontrada en [SO englisch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/521382/1423096)

```
for /d /r "C:\carpeta inicial" %d in (nombrex) do @if exist "%d" rd /s/q "%d"
```

> Pero primero probar con un echo para no borrar cosas que no son

```
for /d /r "C:\carpeta inicial" %d in (nombrex) do @if exist "%d" echo "%d"
```

Ejemplo:

```
for /d /r "D:\mnt\web" %d in (node_modules) do @if exist "%d" echo "%d"
```

https://stackoverflow.com/q/521382/1423096

Comment: Dice no se esperaba d" echo "d" en este momento. cual sera el error?

Comment: versión de windows/consola ?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: puede que necesites permisos para acceder en el disco c: también probaría poner una carpeta dentro del arbol como inicial por si es que se queda sin memoria

Answer (score -1):

- **Alerta** :
  **Debes tener mucho cuidado porque generalmente el drive `C:\` es el usado por tu computadora y no por los discos duros externos.**

Primero indica posicionarte en el directorio del drive (como ejemplo E:\ ) y posteriormente elimina su contenido, te pedirá confirmación:

```
cd E:\TEMP
del *.*
```

Pero puedes tener dentro subdirectorios y contenido dentro de los mismos por lo tanto esta es la forma correcta para eliminar el contenido de estos directorios.

```
cd E:\TEMP
del *.* /s /f /q
```

**Si deseas eliminar todo el contenido, incluyendo archivos y directorios** se realiza de esta forma:

```
   rmdir /s /q E:\TEMP
```